# Run .net core unittests in IBM Cloud

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, ibm-cloud, devops, xunit

Need some input regarding the DevOps in IBM Cloud.

We have got initial setup and in the delivery pipeline there exists a step for unit tests.
Today there is an attempt to call a script:
"Test runner script not found: ./tests/run-tests.sh"
Is there an expectation that there should be a script named run-tests.sh?
And if so, how could this look like when having a .net core -repository with xunit -based unittests?

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep as much stuff as possible under source code control.  Add a source code repository to your "toolchain", like GitHub (Repository type existing) and specify a Repository URL to a repository you own that contains the test.

Now back in your `pipeline` when you create a stage the input panel sill allow you to specify the repo configured above.  Your input jobs, like the test job, will have the github source in the current working directory.

Comment: Hi! I'm not really following what you mean. We already have a .net core -repository with xunit-based unittests, laying in IBMs git repository.
What is unclear, is how one trigger these unit tests from the "unit test -step" in the IBM DevOps pipeline builder. That's my really my question, what I'm trying to explain...